# IF and Vlookup in one formula

Tags: if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

What is wrong with my code?

I have 2 criteria that I need matched, and `If True` then `vlookup` the company unit number.

```
=IF(AND(B20=Sheet1!$B$3:$B$2718,Sheet1!$K3:$K2718="C"),VLOOKUP(B20,Sheet1!$B$3:$D$2718,3,0))
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you.  This site thrives on feedback.  If it worked please mark as correct by clicking on the check mark by the answer.  If it did not work please let me know what went wrong so I can better the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If functions by themselves will not filter the data like you want.

You will want to use the following Array formula.

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$D$3:$D$2718,MATCH(1,(B20=Sheet1!$B$3:$B$2718)*(Sheet1!$K3:$K2718="C"),0))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.